# WP_Query with Custom Field Parameter (checkbox)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to set up a custom query that returns only posts that **do not** have a custom meta field checkbox is checked. The checkbox meta field id is `position-filled`.

Here is the code I have:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'jobs',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post__not_in' => array(get_the_id()),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'position-filled',
            'value' => 'on', // also tried passing null and removing 'compare'
            'compare' => '!=' // also tried 'NOT LIKE'
        )
    ),
);
$customQuery = new WP_Query($args);
```

However, this returns no posts (I have made certain there are posts **without** the checkbox checked.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Update: I think it might have something to do with the custom field not being set until you actually toggle the checkbox. Is there a way to check if the custom field exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into similar issues when adding custom fields to *existing* posts/pages where I needed to search on "unchecked" or "unselected" fields.

It boils down to the fact that the query is **actually** saying, "Give me posts where the meta key (position-filled) *is* populated, but not populated with a value of 'on'".

Does it work if you re-save your post with the checkbox being unchecked?

If so, you might also try using the `'compare'` value of `'NOT EXISTS'`.  Although I believe if you use `NOT EXISTS` and then someone saves an older post without the checkbox being checked, it *will* exist (with a blank value).

**[edit]**

I forgot to mention that you can build a query with *either* situation being true (the `NOT EXISTS` *or* it does exist but the value is blank/unchecked).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'jobs',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post__not_in' => array(get_the_id()),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'position-filled',
            'value' => 'on',
            'compare' => '!='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'position-filled',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    )
);
```

You can chain multiple comparisons together and using the `relation` property of `OR`, either one should return true.

Comment: That seems to do it! I think it actually removes the custom field if you uncheck the checkbox. Which means I should be able to just check if the field exists, instead of the value but having both options seems like a great solution. Thank!

Comment: @Phil That's great!  Have fun!